# google protocol buffers how definition List<Object> in protocol buffers proto file

Tags: java, protocols

Java class has a `List<Object>` Property ,
 how  definition `List<Object>` in protocol buffers proto file,as google protocol buffers no support Object of java world
 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, protocol buffer message types exist independently of standard Java value types, or sometimes Java value types are implemented as wrappers around protocol buffers.

In this specific case, however, the protocol buffer compiler compiles `repeated` fields to Java `List`s.  Of course, you'll need to figure out how to protobuffify the objects *in* the list, but your question doesn't give us enough information to help with that.

Comment: for example: company has some employee ,so Comapny class must be has a propery List<Employee> ,how to defintion google protocol buffers,others property omitted

Comment: Remember, you can't write a protocol buffer that connects to a preexisting class -- you have to make your preexisting class connect to a protocol buffer.  So you have to write an `Employee` message type, a `Company` message type with a `repeated Employee` field, and then tell your classes how to convert to the generated protocol buffer class.

Comment: @Wasserman  but I want to change `List<Employee>` to `List<Object>` ,as Object is super class in Java . in the case ,how to defined .proto    thanks for you reply

Comment: ...You're giving nowhere near enough information for me to be able to help you.  If you could provide code, I might be able to help more.

Comment: eg 
java code :
`public class CustomerRequest{
  private Class class;
  private Method method;
  ...//others omitted
}`

proto
customer_request.protol
...//what is it write here ?


I want to defined a CustomerReqeust class by google protocol buffer,how to write the .proto file ,becuase Calss and Method are standard Java value types

Comment: You can't just serialize any Java value type to a protocol buffer.  You can _only_ serialize Java classes that were generated by `protoc`.  You might be able to serialize `Class` using Java's default serialization, and pass that to a protocol message as a `byte[]`, but you certainly can't serialize `Method`.